# Sum whole column plus a single row of another column and display in a third column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sum, window-functions

here is my problem i do have a query the returns to me this table

```
select * from basic_table;
```

```
|----network----|--- previa ----|--- month---|--- organic_value----|---financial_value-----|
 Rental                  1              1          1000                  1250                 
 Rental                  1              3          3750                  3750
 Service                 2              1           2000                 2200
 Maintance               1              2           350                   500
```

what i need is to sum **all the organic_value where the previa is the same** + financial_value of each month

so the final  table would be

```
|----network----|--- previa ----|--- month---|--- organic_value----|---financial_value-----| ---NEW_COLUMN--|
 Rental                  1              1          1000                  1250                 (1k + 3,75+0,35k) = 5100 + 1,25k = 6350
 Rental                  1              3          3750                  3750                 (5100) + 3,75k = 8850
 Service                 2              1           2000                 2200                  2000 + 2200 = 4200
 Maintance               1              2           350                   500                  (5100 + 500) =5600
```

any tips how to tackle this problem?

Comment: I don't follow the logic.  Where does the 5100 come from?  It is there twice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: as I understand the question, that's the sum of `organic_value` for `previa = 1`.

Comment: the new column you should sum all the organic value of a specific previa (thats why 5100) plus the financial value of the row.





eg. row 4 the previa is 1, so, sum of organic values of previa 1 => 5100 + financial value of that row (500) , final result  is  5600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a window sum:

```
select t.*, 
    financial_value  + sum(organic_value) over(partition by previa) as new_column
from mytable t
```